# Integrating AdMob through Google Play Services with Unity 3D

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob, google-play-services

Following [this tutorial](http://fastegggames.com/blog/2013/3/30/tutorial-admob) I started working on integrating AdMob into Unity, but as this uses an older version I had to make some changes to update it to the Google Play Services version, but I think I may have messed up.

I imported all the required libraries into both Unity 3D's Plugins/Android and Eclipse's Java Build Path and Order and Export.

Every time I call the script in Unity the game crashes and LogCat says it had an error with a tag "AndroidRuntime" "at admob.admob$1.run(admob.java:52) which is this line

```
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Here's my AdMobController.js from Unity:

```
#pragma strict

public class AdMobController extends MonoBehaviour {

    private static var s_Controller : AdMobController;
    private static var jo:AndroidJavaObject;

    function Awake()
    {
        s_Controller = this;
        #if UNITY_ANDROID
        jo = new AndroidJavaObject("admob.admob");
        #endif
    }
}
```

#### File admob.java

```
package admob;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;
import com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class admob{

    //  private String pubID = "ADMOB_ID_HERE"; //Your public AdMob ID. Make sure this is correct, or you won't get any credit for the Ad.
    private Activity activity; //Store the android main activity
    private AdView adView; //The AdView we will display to the user
    private LinearLayout layout; //The layout the AdView will sit on

    //Constructor
    public admob() {
        activity = UnityPlayer.currentActivity;

        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                /*
                    layout = new LinearLayout(activity);

                    activity.addContentView(layout, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                    adView = new AdView(activity);
                    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
                    adView.setAdUnitId(pubID);
                    AdRequest.Builder adRequestBuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();
                    adView.loadAd(adRequestBuilder.build());
                */

                layout = new LinearLayout(activity);

                // Create the adView.
                adView = new AdView(activity);
                adView.setAdUnitId("MY_AD_ID"); //Yes, I put the correct ID here. I only deleted it before posting here.
                adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);

                // Add the adView to it.
                layout.addView(adView);

                activity.addContentView(layout, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)       // Emulator
                    .addTestDevice("AC98C820A50B4AD8A2106EDE96FB87D4") // Test phone. Not my actual phone because I could
                                                                       // not call AdRequest to get the ID for it.
                    .build();

                // Load the adView with the ad request.
                Log.d("unity321", "unity321");
                adView.loadAd(adRequest);

                layout.addView(adView.getRootView(), new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                // Code in here will run on the UI thread of this application
            }
        });
    }
}
```

AdMob manifest from Eclipse:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.admob.admob"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                   android:value="google_play_services_version"/>
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
                  android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
</manifest>
```

And finally the manifest in the plugins folder in Unity used to override the Unity built manifest (NOTE: android:value="google_play_services_version" is changed because with the @integer/ both Unity and Eclipse said no value was found and would not export)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.TESTCOMPANY.TESTAPP"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
          android:versionName="1.0"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:installLocation="auto">
    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
                      android:normalScreens="true"
                      android:largeScreens="true"
                      android:xlargeScreens="true"
                      android:anyDensity="true" />
    <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
                 android:label="@string/app_name"
                 android:debuggable="true">
         <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity"
                   android:label="@string/app_name"
                   android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
                   android:launchMode="singleTask"
                   android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale">
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
             </intent-filter>
             <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity"
                        android:value="true" />
             <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik"
                        android:value="true" />
             <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                        android:value="google_play_services_version"/>
         </activity>
         <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
                   android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9"
              android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch"
                  android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct"
                  android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: [solved here] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41531875/interestial-ads-not-showing-on-live-android-device-for-game-build-in-unity-4-6?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 1):

Yep, this is what I did. 
Make another folder in unity; where your plugins are.

Mine is Assets/plugins/android/
You need Assets/plugins/android/res/values

In the values folder save this in an xml file named values.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<resources>

<integer name="google_play_services_version">4132500</integer>

</resources>
```

Comment: What do I call the xml?

Comment: I added the values to both the eclipse project and unity (had to remove the extra dash though :3), now I can build in unity with the @integer/ value but it still crashes on adView.loadAd (AndroidRuntime)

Comment: Should have only needed to add it to your Unity project, it is in the proper location in Eclipse by default (if you have properly setup your eclipse project and linked the playservices.jar) Although, I do select the values.xml in the res folder when I export from eclipse, but I am not sure if it does anything. (Don't know where that dash came from. I copied that directly from my values.xml).

Answer (score 0):

Copy the folder `google_play_services` from `<Android sdk>/extras/google/` to the `Assets/Plugins/Android` folder in `Unity` and build the project again.