# Interestial Ads Not Showing on Live Android Device for Game Build in Unity 4.6

Tags: android, admob, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity Version ==> 4.6.0 
Admob Version ==> [Google Mobile Ads Unity Plugin v3.1.3](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/releases/tag/3.1.3)

I am using below code to show interstitial ads.

```
public const string adsIdAndroid = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712";
  public void RequestInterstitial()
    {
        try
        {
            if (!AdsFlag)
            {
                Debug.Log("Requested Interstitial");                          
               // Initialize an InterstitialAd.
                interstitial = new InterstitialAd(adsIdAndroid);
                // Create an empty ad request.
                AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
                // Load the interstitial with the request.
                interstitial.LoadAd(request);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }

    }

    public void ShowInterstitial()
    {
        try
        {
            //Debug.Log("Try Show InterstitialAd");
            if (!AdsFlag)
            {
                if (interstitial.IsLoaded())
                {
                    Debug.Log("Show InterstitialAd");
                    interstitial.Show();
                    AdsFlag = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.Log("InterstitialAd Not Loaded");
                    RequestInterstitial();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
    }
```

I am calling above function as below :

```
    void Start()
        {
            AdsFlag = false;
            RequestInterstitial();
    }
 void Update()
    {
        ShowInterstitial();

}
```

Unity Log As Below :

```
Requested Interstitial
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
Dummy CreateInterstitialAd
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
Dummy LoadAd
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
Dummy IsLoaded
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
Show InterstitialAd
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
Dummy ShowInterstitial
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
```

**But on Real Android Device , ads not showing up..** 
How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many of us facing similar problem with unity and admob

I just solved this problem by following below steps:

1) I have deleted **google-play-services_lib** folder at Assets\Plugins\Android
2) Then Select Menu Assets -> Play Service Resolver -> Android Resolver -> Resolve Client Jars.

I just followed this 2 steps and now my google ads working fine. 
Maybe this answer help you to figure out problem.